# Как переделать виджет QTextEdit, чтобы скопированный из буфера обмена html-текст отображался в обработанном виде?

Tags: html, c++, qt, clipboard

У меня есть программа:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){   
    QApplication app(argc, argv);       
    QTextEdit te;
    te.setHtml("<!DOCTYPE html>"
        "<html>"
        "<body style = \"background-color:powderblue;\">"
        "<h1>My First Heading< / h1>"
        "<p>My first paragraph.< / p>"
        "< / body>"
        "< / html>");
    te.resize(500, 300);
    te.show();  
    return app.exec();  
}
```

При запуске появляется следующее окно:

[image: html в обработанном виде]

И есть другая программа:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){   
    QApplication app(argc, argv);       
    QTextEdit te;   
    te.resize(500, 300);
    te.show();  
    return app.exec();  
}
```

При копировании в окно html текста из буфера обмена появляется следующее:

[image: plain text]

Как сделать так, чтобы html-текст, вставляемый в QTextEdit из буфера обмена отображался в преобразованном виде, как на первом изображении?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У `QTextEdit` есть [виртуальный метод](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#insertFromMimeData), который вызывается при вставке текста через copy-paste и drag-drop. Можно унаследовать свой `TextEdit`, который будет при вставке текста вставлять его как html:

```
class TextEdit : public QTextEdit{
public:
    TextEdit(QWidget *parent = 0):
        QTextEdit(parent)
    {}
protected:
    void insertFromMimeData(const QMimeData *source){
        if(source->hasText()){
            setHtml(source->text());
        }
        else{
            QTextEdit::insertFromMimeData(source);
        }
    }
};
```